# UIPageControl showing incorrect page

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I've got a UIScrollView containing several tables, and a UIPageControl keeping track of which page the user is currently viewing. It works fine UNTIL i start scrolling up on the tableview, at which point the UIPageControl adjusts and says (incorrectly) that we are on the first page.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
  if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
    return;
  }

  /*
   *  We switch page at 50% across
   */
  CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
  int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
  pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

and then this as well:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
  pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
}
```

Not sure what exactly is causing this to happen . . . any ideas? Im stumped :(

Comment: pageControlIsChangingPage is returning YES then.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would cause the UIPageControl to suddenly display as if we are on the first page. What am I missing?

Comment: When you execute `return;` the function exits.

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure why that is causing this result. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue was that both the UITableView and the UIScrollView, since they both had the delegates set to self, were calling the same scrollview methods. I added a tag to the main scrollview, and then accounted for it by performing a check on the Tag when adjusting the page, like so

```
if (_scrollView.tag == 100) {

CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;

}
```

finally

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll the page, does it scrolls correctly?

```
if (pageControlIsChangingPage)
  return;
```

It seems when you do not change page (i.e. you scroll the tableview instead), `return`'ll not be executed. And so

```
CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;
```

part will be executed, at this moment, `_scrollView.contentOffset.x` will less than `pageWidth / 2` (even can be `0`), as you just scroll up/down, and as a result, the `page` turn out to be `1`.

Comment: Yes it all works perfectly as long as I don't scroll the tableviews. Not really sure how to tell the uipagecontrol to ignore those however

Comment: OK here is something odd: If I scroll upward on a piece of the scrollview that does not have the uitableview on it, the page control DOESN'T make the incorrect switch to page 1. So it seems somehow the uitableview is interfering.

Comment: Im thinking perhaps the tableview,since its a uiscrollview subclass and shares the same delegate, is calling the same methods and so the content offset is always 0?

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser Put a log into `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`, check whether it is executed every time you scroll the tableview. And you can try to comment out the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` either.

Comment: It is indeed executing. I think the tableview must be interfering somehow but I'm not sure how to overcome the issue

Comment: I also Logged out the content offset. When I scroll horizontally it works perfectly. However, when I scroll vertically on the table, it tells me the content offset is 0. This must be referring to the content offset of the tableview correct?